# Binding visibility of a control in a User Control in wpf

Tags: wpf

I need to show hide a control in a User Control by binding the visibility to a property. I am very new to WPF. Can you please show me how to do this? Please see my code below:

```
public partial class QrScanner : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool ShowProgressBar { get; set; }
    private void _qrSerialController_ReceivedBytes(string str)
    {
        ShowProgressBar = true;
        Text = str.Trim();

        try
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine((QrMessage));
            _qrMessageHolder = sb.ToString();
            SendQrMessage(_qrMessageHolder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($@"An error occured in connecting the QR Scanner: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => QrMessage;
        set
        {
            QrMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler == null) return;
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Converter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

 <ProgressBar
    x:Name="ProgressBar"
    IsIndeterminate="True"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowProgressBar, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to implement proper `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You need to call `OnPropertyChanged()` from the setter of `ShowProgressBar`

Comment: Every property binded to your UI must call OnPropertyChanged method. Call that method like this OnPropertyChanged("ShowProgressBar"); in your setter

Comment: @Aakanksha With the `CallerMemberName` attribute it is not necessary to include `PropertyName`. `OnPropertyChanged();` will work. But if you absolutely want to include it, then better to use `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowProgressBar))` instead of `OnPropertyChanged("ShowProgressBar");` to minimize mistakes and typos.

Answer (score 1):

In the Set/setter of "ShowProgressBar" you need to call OnPropertyChanged() in the same way you are doing so for the property "Text".